# TrustStore and Keystore during 2 way SSL validation

Tags: java, ssl, jks

I have been unable to find a solution to this problem elsewhere so I am hoping someone here can provide some insight. My setup below:

keystore, myKeys.jks:

```
mine-private, 3/6/2014, PrivateKeyEntry
mine-trusted, 3/6/2014, trustedCertEntry
```

trust store, myTrust.jks:

```
trusted-cert-1, 3/6/2014, trusterCertEntry
trusted-cert-2, 3/6/2014, trusterCertEntry
mine-trusted, 3/6/2014, trustedCertEntry   <-- this is mine
```

What ends up happening is I get a message stating that my client has not been authenticated.  Let me know if there is more information necessary

Responses to questions:

```
First off: what classes/library are you using? Simply the default https in java?
```

Apache HTTP Client, code below:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://foo.bar.baz/rest");  
client.executeMethod(method);
```

Secondly: how exactly are you registering the keystore/truststore? You need a custom SSLContext for this.

Don't think so, but could be wrong

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path/to/myTrust.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="password"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="path/to/myKeys.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="password"
```

Comment: Have you checked (I don't know by heart) if the apache http client also uses these system properties?

Answer (score 1):

First off: what classes/library are you using? Simply the default https in java?

Secondly: how exactly are you registering the keystore/truststore? You need a custom SSLContext for this.

Initial example:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance();
KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyFactory.init(keyStore, password);

TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustFactory.init(trustStore);

context.init(keyFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Most libraries that I know support setting a custom SSLContext or SSLSocketFactory which can be obtained from the context.

Comment: move this to the comment section so you don't get blasted.  But sure I will gladly provide that information

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html per their tutorial that is all that is necessary.  Unless they botched the docs.

Comment: On the page you linked I don't see (though I only quickly scanned) a reference to the system properties. What I did see was: Protocol myhttps = new Protocol("https", new MySSLSocketFactory(), 443); Note the custom socket factory.

Comment: PS: http client 3.x is really old. Consider updating.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample that does the exact same thing. You can find the particular code in [1].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/v5.0.7/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/endpoint/util/TenantMgtAdminServiceClient.java#L155